Fixing clipped geometries at WMTS tile boundaries in QGIS Server
I'm experiencing an issue with QGIS Server's WMTS service where geometries are clipped or misaligned at tile boundaries, creating visible gaps between tiles. While I know MapProxy and MapCache can solve this using metatiles, I'm specifically looking for a solution within QGIS Server itself.

Current setup:

QGIS Server version: 3.34
Apache web server
Ubuntu Server

I've tried adjusting the QGIS Server rendering settings but haven't found a way to implement a tile buffer or prevent the geometry clipping. Has anyone solved this issue directly in the QGIS Server without using external caching servers?
